# I can hear it pinging and talking, but it can't hear anything

Tags: connection, switch, wireshark

I got one-way connectivity to some devices and sometimes(randomly) no connectivity, with odd link-status LED lighting.

There are 1 PC(mine) and 2 routers('A' and 'B') connected to a switch(unmanaged) and 2 more PCs behind router 'B'. My PC and router 'A' are fine seeing each other, but we can't ping router 'B' or PCs behind it(nor any other sort of connectivity).

But strange is, Wireshark shows me the other PC's ping request reaching mine and mine replies, but the other PC says "timed out". All devices have static IPs in the same subnet assigned to them.

More details:

The switch's link-status LED for the cable to router 'B' has some strange behaviors:

1. It is sometimes off, despite router 'B' is always on. I noticed when it gets on, people are working with the unconnected PCs behind router 'B'.
2. I could see the one-way ping requests, but the LED was lighting for a second then off for more than two(I'm not sure if it's the 'Idle Connection' lighting or not).

Also, in Wireshark sometimes I see router 'B' sending RIP responses and other devices introducing themselves and etc., but sometimes not.

Routers' LAN ports are used and their RIP setting is both set to RIPv1. Both routers and the switch are consumer-level devices(Just in case somebody wants to question their implementations of network protocols). Routers are actually ADSL Modem Routers. Both routers are updated to their latest firmware.

Everything was working fine before I replaced router 'A' with the switch, but now getting router 'A' back to the place didn't solve the problem! Also tested connecting cable from router 'B' directly to my PC with no light and no luck.

EDIT:

Because of random and odd connections, I thought maybe there is a non-software issue involved. The cable between the switch and router 'B' is a CAT6 SFTP which has about 100 m length(50 m per EDIT 3), which is quite usual for CAT6, but I thought if the cable has occasionally much of electromagnetic fileds, could it somehow create these strange behaviors?

EDIT 2:

Is there any necessity to use T568A for the "twisted pairs" to work correctly? I've just used the same order of colors for both ends without attention to T568A (and as I said, it had worked well for some time).

EDIT 3:

I patched it using T658A and nothing changed, including strange behaviors!

At first, both LEDs was off, so I thought I've messed the jacks up, but when I replaced the switch with router 'A', it's LED got fully on, with LED on router 'B' still off! And Wireshark showed nothing.

Today, without any action, it got exactly like before: switch's LED was lit, Wireshark showed some broadcasts coming from router 'B' and the PCs behind it, and still they can't hear me pinging them.

I noticed the RIP responses of router 'A' and 'B' are being broadcasted quite beside each other, each one repeating it after the other router, for about 3-4 times, then they're silent for some seconds, where several other communications by other devices do happen.

(And I was wrong about the length. The operators said it's just 50 meters.)

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrggghhhh! it was the jack! The jack's size made it a very little bit loose in router 'B'. How much unexpected! It was only when I tried to cross-check the routers that I noticed I have to wrestle with the jack to make it's link-status LED lit.

But how could it cause the one-way connection? Interesting ...

Thanks everybody for helping.

Comment: Different wires are used for sending then receiving. A typical Ethernet cable has 4 pairs of wires. For 100BaseT you use 2 pairs and for 1000BaseTX you use all 4 pairs. If the receiving pairs are making contact and the sending pairs aren't, you can see the above behavior. See this picture http://www.archonmagnus.com/computing/elec/diagrams/ethernetCableDiagram.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's quite important to use the T568A (or B) wiring schemes for ***reliable*** ethernet performance.  Unshielded Twisted Pair cables are only able to reliably carry high-speed signals at full-duplex for distances up to 100 m when specific wires are selected:  For 100BASE-TX, The four wires that are not transmitting signals are just as important as the four that are:  They serve as shielding to prevent cross-talk, interference. echos, and fade.  For 1000BASE-T*, all four pairs are used, but it's still important to separate wires carrying certain signals from others that might be carrying signals that would create destructive or constructive interference on neighbouring wires.

For short cables, at lower line rates, it's quite possible to 'get away' with non-standard wiring, but as distances approach the specification limits, and the fastest line rates, selecting the proper pairs to send, receive, and dampen signals becomes more critical.

So, if you're not using one of the specified cabling pinouts, then your connection will be unreliable.  This may manifest in intermittent connectivity, one-way transmission problems, pattern sensitivity, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using T568 standard was already noted by the other dear helper in the comments of his post. And I've just written the result in EDIT 3.

Comment: In addition, any electric field can create problems so you can also encounter problems if you have Ethernet wires in close proximity to mains power lines or anything else that creates an electric field.

Answer (score 0):

Your second router has a firewall and/or NAT enabled which prevents anything originated on the WAN side from reaching the LAN side.

You probably just want to set it up as a bridge so that you have a single LAN.

Comment: Thanks but I said: "Routers' LAN ports are used".

Comment: If you are seeing RIP advertisements, you are routing, not switching. You want to set up the interior router as a bridge (disable routing, DHCP, NAT,etc.).

Comment: If router 'B' is routing, then how is it that I can see ping requests from PCs behind it for a local address at 192.168.1.x to my PC? And if just "seeing" RIP advertisements means routing, how is it that I see them from router 'A' as well?

Comment: RIP stands for Routing Information Protocol. It is a routing protocol, and it has no place on a network where you don't want to do routing. I think that if you disable RIP, set the interior router to be a bridge, and reset the IP addressing on your hosts connected to the interior router, all will be well.

Comment: I will try it when I get there(tomorrow morning). Thanks.

Comment: It had no option to disable RIP. The only option it had was for RIP version(=v1) and direction(=both). But I couldn't find out how to set the router as a bridge for LAN(=for devices that are connected to LAN ports). Maybe the router has gone crazy and assumes LAN ports as WAN(Could that be? I'm wishing for a cross-check). I tried another factory reset of router 'B' with no luck, and also tried disabling SPI(which blocks all the traffic initiated from WAN(=DSL PPPoE) becuase PCs behind router 'B' have no proprietary firewalls) but no luck. (Also please see the edit on my post)

Comment: Once you set it to bridge, you need to have the hosts pull new addresses from DHCP. You need to make sure DHCP is disabled on that device too - just a pure bridge.

Comment: 1:Do you suggest using the WAN port and then bridge 'em? Because I still can't understand bridging a router for devices that are connected to LAN ports(I tried DHCP relay to router 'A' today, but they couldn't get IP) 2:I'm afraid there is a deceiving faulty device. So I wish to cross-check router 'A' and 'B' tomorrow. Please enlighten me about the EDIT 2 as well.

Comment: If you set the router to bridge and disable the firewall, NAT and DHCP, you could connect the router using it's WAN port. At this point, it is merely a switch (bridge) just as if you bought a switch and connected it via the uplink port on the switch. As long as the cable is a straight-through or a crossover cable, and the pairs are not split, it doesn't matter if it is T568-A or T568-B. You must pay attention to the pairs (1-2,3-6,4-5,7-8). The first two pairs for 10/100 Mb, and all four for 1 Gb.

Comment: Really?! I didn't know that I must pay attention to the pairs! Since I'd been only wiring CAT5 before this. I guess the cable(=myself :) ) was the culprit! :) Going to try it tomorrow. Many thanks for your time and efforts.